# Why isn't my ruby-on-rails sign-in form working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm trying to create a very rudimentary sign-in form. It doesn't have a password or username; simply a name text field and a submit button

Here's it's code:

```
<%= form_for :current_user, url: { :controller => 'sessions', :action=>'new' } do |f| %>
<p id='name'>Name:<%= f.text_field :current_user, placeholder: 'First Last', :id => 'current_user' %></p>
<%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

When I submit the name rails gives me this error

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/calendar/signin"
```

The route I have set up for the login is here:

```
match 'calendar/signin', to: 'sessions#new', via: 'get'
```

And here is the action for sessions#new

```
def new
end
```

So how do I make the form submit to GET rather than POST, is what I guess I'm asking.

Answer (score 3):

Change your route to post

```
match 'calendar/signin', to: 'sessions#new', via: 'post'
```